# How to handle sub-route and a root route in the same ingress

Tags: google-cloud-platform, next.js, url-routing, load-balancing, kubernetes-ingress

I have one ingress handling traffic for 2 different services:

```
rules:
    - http:
        paths:
          - path: /stats
            backend:
              serviceName: info-dashboard
              servicePort: 80
          - path: /*
            backend:
              serviceName: portal
              servicePort: 80
```

I also have URL rewrite rules for the `info-dashboard`. Rewrite `/stats -> /` when the traffic is sent to the service. Because the app behind the backend service expects its endpoint hits to start with `/`, not `/stats`.

So, the issue is that hitting `/stats` on the LB is fine, but subsequent calls fail (eg. automated app calls to fetch javascript and other logic). They fail because they try to load from `/`, which is a different app.

The app is a Next.js app. So, I also tried setting up a [basePath](https://nextjs.org/docs/api-reference/next.config.js/basepath). But the issue persists.

Actually, if I remove the `/stats -> /` redirect rule from the LB, any hits to `/stats` just direct me to the other app on the ingress - the `portal`. I'm confused why and how this works.

Am I missing something in the setup?

Answer (score 0):

From the k8s-ingress point of view everything is fine. It looks like the problem lays in your `info-dashboard` application, which doesn't "know" that it's running behind a proxy. To fix this your application should be configured using some kind of a basePath/rootPath flag (depending on your application) pointing to `/stats` so it can hit `/stats` as configured.

Comment: The app is a Next.js app and it does have a `basePath` configured. 
I forgot to mention this. I will add it to the OP.

Comment: Could you please provide your Services, Deployments and full Ingress manifests? I'd like to replicate this on my environment. Also how did you deploy Ingress Controller? Using Helm or [Nginx Docs](https://kubernetes.github.io/ingress-nginx/deploy/)?